# Asynchronous function returns null

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart

The dayManager.getDay() returns a null instead of a Map

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("init");
    getDay();
  }

  void getDay() async {
    Future<Map<int, int>> dayExistingValueMap = dayManager.getDay();
    dayExistingValueMap.then((map) {
      print('dayExisting ____ $map');
    });
  }
```

but when I print it out beforee returning it, the Map contains all the values.

```
    Future<Map<int, int>> getDay() async {
    final Future<Database> dbFuture = databaseHelper.initializeDatabase();
    dbFuture.then((database) async {
      final bool checkIfExists = await databaseHelper.checkIfExist(day.dateStr);
      if (checkIfExists) {
        Day dbDay = await databaseHelper.getDaySingle(day.dateStr);
        print('_${dbDay.valueMap}');
        return dbDay.valueMap;
      } else {
        return this.day.valueMap;
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: try this Future<Map<int, int>> dayExistingValueMap = await dayManager.getDay();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning the value within the closure inside the `then`, so as far as the `getDay` method is concerned, you aren't returning anything. My recommendation is to not use `then` at all, since it directly causes these kinds of confusions. (Not to mention calling `then` defeats the purpose of marking your method as `async` which is to be able to use `await`).

```dart
Future<Map<int, int>> getDay() async {
  final database = await databaseHelper.initializeDatabase();
  final bool checkIfExists = await databaseHelper.checkIfExist(day.dateStr);
  if (checkIfExists) {
    Day dbDay = await databaseHelper.getDaySingle(day.dateStr);
    print('_${dbDay.valueMap}');
    return dbDay.valueMap;
  } else {
    return this.day.valueMap;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is returning null since you're not actually returning anything. You need to return the result of `dbFuture.then`, like so:

```dart
    Future<Map<int, int>> getDay() async {
      final Future<Database> dbFuture = databaseHelper.initializeDatabase();
      return dbFuture.then((database) async {
        final bool checkIfExists = await databaseHelper.checkIfExist(day.dateStr);
        if (checkIfExists) {
          Day dbDay = await databaseHelper.getDaySingle(day.dateStr);
          print('_${dbDay.valueMap}');
          return dbDay.valueMap;
        } else {
          return this.day.valueMap;
        }
      });
    }
```

`Future.then` returns a `Future` that completes to the return value of the closure provided.

Comment: Technically correct, but this method invalidates the purpose of `async`.

Comment: I wouldn't say "invalidates" is the right word, but you're right that it would be cleaner to make full use of `async-await`. Regardless, forgetting to actually return from a method will always result in its result being null.

Comment: Maybe not "invalidates" as much as "makes redundant". The outer method is marked as `async` but it never `await`s anything and it explicitly returns a future. Using `async-await` would result in cleaner code, but if nothing else the `getDay` method here has no reason to be marked as `async`. (Personally, I don't know why explicitly returning a future in an `async` method isn't marked as a warning by the dart linter.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `return dbFuture.then((database) async {` we can use `final Database dbFuture = await databaseHelper.initializeDatabase();`

```
Future<Map<int, int>> getDay() async {
    final Database dbFuture = await databaseHelper.initializeDatabase();

      final bool checkIfExists = await databaseHelper.checkIfExist(day.dateStr);
      if (checkIfExists) {
        Day dbDay = await databaseHelper.getDaySingle(day.dateStr);
        print('_${dbDay.valueMap}');
        return dbDay.valueMap;
      } else {
        return this.day.valueMap;
      }

  }
```